# Dynamic SAS Stored Process Based Web Application

Tags: web-applications, sas, sas-stored-process

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-9wq8{border-color:inherit;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}
.tg .tg-za14{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:bottom}
.tg .tg-7zrl{text-align:left;vertical-align:bottom}
.tg .tg-nrix{text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}
</style>
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-za14">Manager</th>
    <th class="tg-za14">Sub Manager</th>
    <th class="tg-za14">Staff</th>
    <th class="tg-7zrl">Response</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-9wq8" rowspan="5">A</td>
    <td class="tg-9wq8" rowspan="3">A1</td>
    <td class="tg-za14">A1A</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-za14">A1B</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-za14">A1C</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-9wq8" rowspan="2">A2</td>
    <td class="tg-za14">A2A</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-za14">A2B</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-nrix" rowspan="9">B</td>
    <td class="tg-nrix" rowspan="4">B1</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">B1A</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">B2B</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">B2C</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">B2D</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-nrix" rowspan="2">B2</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">B2A</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">B2B</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-nrix" rowspan="3">B3</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">B3A</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">B3B</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">B3C</td>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">Yes</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to use SAS Stored process based web application with dynamic functionality.

Suppose I have list of managers, sub managers and staff.

I want manager to provide a response at staff level which I want to store in some database.

I want to check feasibility on Stored process and stored process based web application.

Requirement is that only manager should fill the response. And manager can have any number of sub managers within him/her and any number of staff within sub manager.

Code attached to see sample hierarchy.

Comment: Do you want the stored process (SP) to read the web page you show?  If only a manager should fill in a response to a SP generated page that sounds like a SAS server admin question about setting read properties on a stored process, or the submit handler needs to check automatic variable METAUSER. A better forum for this question (which needs better explaining) is probably SAS communities.

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is.  If you're serious about building web apps on SAS though, you can check out these sample SASjs apps:  https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Asasjs-app+org%3Asasjs+fork%3Atrue&type=repositories

Answer (score 0):

Our product (Data Controller for SAS) would actually do this for you, out of the box - https://datacontroller.io

Just set the row level permissions accordingly: https://docs.datacontroller.io/row-level-security/

Comment: I edited the answer.  Data Controller has a free tier, and the source is available, and limited support is available for free, but yeah it's not free as in libre.